# Cpanel not recognizing the wordpress categories and tags

Tags: wordpress, cpanel

I have recently started hosting a website and using cPanel interface to import my wordpress.com blog.

I exported my blog WordPress using admin-export tool to a zip file and successfully imported the pages & posts in cPanel using WordPress import plugin.

Everything is looking good except the tags and categories I had on wordpress.com are no more available in cPanel.

e.g. I have few tags (`cast`, `datatypes`, `date`, `time` ) and categories(`Programming`, `Tutorials`) defined on my original blog

https://qkdb.wordpress.com/2017/08/07/temporal-datatypes/

but cpanel-wordpress is not showing any categories on my new website :

https://tickdatascience.com/wp/2017/08/07/temporal-datatypes/

Am I missing anything?

Comment: I don't think the theme which you are using is same. try using same theme because it depends on theme structure if the tags kr categories are to be visible or not

Comment: Don't think it was a theme issue. I tried multiple themes but it never worked.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by :

1. creating a new category `kdb`
2. selected all the posts and applied the bulk action to assign the above category to all posts.
3. it automatically recovered all my tags and categories on all the posts.
4. then I removed the category `kdb`.